# Getting inputs to auto-complete/suggest when preventing default form behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

Interesting bug here that seems to be limited to IE and Webkit.
I have a basic form setup:

```
<div id="output">Form output is displayed here</div>

<form id="myForm" action="#" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" id="usernameInput" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Now if I just submit the form through a normal page refresh, the next time I go to type text into the input field, I will get the browser's default auto-suggest dropdown (this is the intended behavior). However, if I highjack the form submission behavior in order to do an AJAX submit:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function () {
    $('#output').text($('usernameInput').val());
    return false;
});
```

Now when I submit the form, the output div updates, but the previous values that I input into the form aren't stored and no suggestions will be made when you type.

Does anyone have any creative solutions to this problem? Maybe an (*gulp*) iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE and WebKit only remember values that were submitted normally, and since you are submitting it through AJAX, those engines do not remember the values. Instead of an iframe, I would use a jQuery plugin for the autocomplete, like [this one](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete). Of course, with that solution, you will need to maintain a listing of what a user has typed in the past, which shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like that's probably going to be my only option unfortunately. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

test with these modifications in controlling submit:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#output').html($("#usernameInput").val() + "<br />");
});
```

Comment: Returning false from a jQuery event handler is the same as calling preventDefault() and stopPropagation(). Without making a call to preventDefault(), the form gets submitted as a page refresh =[